# after selecting 'Choose one' in drop-down in wicket

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-6, wicket-1.5

I have 3 option in drop-down in DropDownChoice in Apache wicket,
and when I select default 3 options it will add one text field with respective to each choice but when I select default 'choose one' it unable to invisible all the text field which visible when we select any those 3 choices.

For example: products has 3 choices along with their textfield.

```
ChoiceA - textfield1
ChoiceB - textfield2
ChoiceC - textfield3
```

and when we select default 'choose one' it should remove/make invisible all textfield from UI .

Answer (score 1):

When "Choose One" is selected the model object of the DropDownChoice will be *null*. If it is *null* then you should hide the TextFields, otherwise you should show them, i.e. make them visible.